# How to create a MySQL adapter for session.io in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I have a NodeJS project on 2 Google Cloud instances behind a load-balancer. I'm using `socket.io`. I want to share the sessions between the instances.

Usually developers doing it using [socket.io-redies](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis), but I don't want `redis` just for that. I have Cloud SQL (Aka: MySQL), and I want to use MySQL for sharing the sessions.

I have understand the whole index.js of the redis adapter file, except this function:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis/blob/master/index.js#L93

```
Redis.prototype.onmessage = function(channel, msg){
var args = msgpack.decode(msg);
var packet;

if (uid == args.shift()) return debug('ignore same uid');

packet = args[0];

if (packet && packet.nsp === undefined) {
  packet.nsp = '/';
}

if (!packet || packet.nsp != this.nsp.name) {
  return debug('ignore different namespace');
}

args.push(true);

this.broadcast.apply(this, args);
```

};

If I need to get events from the MySQL (subscribe) I think it is not possible. Am I right?

Do you know another solution of sharing `socket.io` between two machines, without using Redis?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Today, it is so easy to lunch redis. So this is what I did: `curl https://get.docker.io | sh & docker run  --restart=always redis` That's all!

Comment: You didn't solve the mysql adapter?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. Session.io need real time events. Redis supports it, MySQL is not supports real-time triggers events. (The truth is that everything possible in MySQL, except when you use managed enviroment)